# Manually add google cardboard viewer profiles

Tags: android, sdk, google-cardboard, virtual-reality

My question is primarily because of a bug in 4.4 and earlier devices. More on it [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/GoogleCardboard/comments/3i3t4z/cardboard_app_connection_error_when_trying_to_set/) and [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/GoogleCardboard/comments/3kyrca/cardboard_vr_app_refuses_to_switch_viewer_type/).

The gist is this

> Something changed recently with the goo.gl/ URL shortening service
>   that breaks the Cardboard app's own QR-code scanner. It only seems to
>   affect Android 4.4 and older versions.

What Im looking to do is add viewer profiles to these devices either using a script via adb or manually copy pasting needed files.

This is for a hackathon I'm organizing in 2 days so timely help is appreciated. Also if it helps the devices we are developing on will be rooted so changes to the filesystem are possible.

Answer (score 0):

The issue with the shortening was fixed and now its possible to once again get viewer profiles added automatically.

On a side note I'd still like to hear if there is a way to side load this manually.